# Dump MySQL Desde Cliente a Servidor en PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, symfony3

Tengo este código con el que creo respaldos de mi base de datos

```
    $dbname = $this->getParameter('database_name');
    $host = $this->getParameter("database_host");
    $user = $this->getParameter("database_user");
    $pass = $this->getParameter('database_password');

    $route = '/usr/moseDump';
    $separador = '/';

    if (!file_exists($route . $separador)) {
        mkdir($separador . $route, 077);
    }

    $backup_file = $route . $separador . $dbname . "_" . date("dmYHis") . ".sql";
    $command = "mysqldump --opt -h " . $host . " -u " . $user . " -p" . $pass . " " . $dbname . " > $backup_file";

    exec($command);
```

Si lo ejecuto localmente, funciona perfecto, pero al momento de ejecutarlo desde un cliente, este simplemente no genera el archivo. Estoy usando apache2 en ubuntu 16.

Comment: En lugar de hacer `exec($command)`, podrías hacer [`passthru($command, $output);`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.passthru.php) `var_dump($output);`, así puedes averiguar porque no te funciona

Comment: Estoy en un problema parecido. El lío es el servidor . Revisa los logs de Symfony var/logs ahí te dará una idea de la solución.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que tienes permisos para esto? El entorno local es una cosa, y el remoto otro... Ejecuta manualmente el comando en el servidor y comprueba que, efectivamente, funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Murianno estoy casi convencido de que es un problema de privilegios.

Cuando ejecutas un comando en local en servidores de desarrollo solemos utilizar el usuario root u otro con x privilegios, mientras que el servidor web al ejecutar las peticiones utiliza el usuario www-data y grupo www-data en apache y nginx.

La solución es sencilla, tienes varias opciones:
1- Agrega el grupo www-data a la carpeta de las copias y asignale permisos

```
chown USUARIO:www-data -R /usr/moseDump -> Asignar grupo a la carpeta  
chmod -R X7X -R /usr/moseDump -> Asigna privilegios al grupo en la carpeta
```

2- (menos recomendada) Modifica el usuario de ejecución de Nginx o Apache al que tenga privilegios en dicha carpeta.